# How to add objects of two PFquery data using parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am having two queries one is friendsrequestQuery and other is user query i want to add all the data of friendrequestQuery details into user query while fetching data from the user Query.

```
NSPredicate *predicate12=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((UserFriendId == %@ )AND (UserId!=%@)) OR ((UserFriendId != %@ )AND (UserId==%@)) ",@"Nwk44aeSrz",@"Nwk44aeSrz",@"Nwk44aeSrz",@"Nwk44aeSrz"];
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendsDetails" predicate:predicate12];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"BlockStatus" equalTo:@"No"];
PFQuery * userQuery = [PFUser query];

[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"UserFriendId" inQuery:innerQuery];
[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"UserId" inQuery:innerQuery];

[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:@"Nwk44aeSrz"];
```

I wil explain the thing what i need exactly is, in innerquery table i am having 10 columns but i need the data of these particular coloum data  converstionid,lastmessage,lastdate while reterving the data of users query.
Now i am getting the details of userquery but not the details of innerquery,so i need the details of Innerquerydetails .
Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off storing pointers as opposed to Id's, this way you can include that data as well.

I will not use predicates, I realize your query is cleaner with predicates, but I think the logic is easier to see with this.  You can convert it back to predicate for yourself.

```
// get your user
PFUser * userForQuery; // set up your user for the query, if it's current user, = [PFUser currentUser];

// first part of predicate
PFQuery * innerQueryA = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendsDetails"];
[innerQueryA whereKey:@"UserFriend" equalTo:userForQuery]; // from  @"UserFriendId"
[innerQueryA whereKey:@"User" notEqualTo:userForQuery]; // from @"UserId"

// second part of predicate
PFQuery * innerQueryB = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendsDetails"];
[innerQueryB whereKey:@"userFriend" notEqualTo:userForQuery]; // from @"UserFriendId"
[innerQueryB whereKey:@"user" equalTo:userForQuery]; // from @"UserId"

// combine
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[innerQueryA, innerQueryB]];
[query whereKey:@"BlockStatus" equalTo:@"No"];

// Now, as you remember, we are storing a pointer in @"User" as opposed to an id @"UserId" as you had it. Because of     
// this, we will use parse's includeKey: feature.

[query includeKey:@"User"]; // tells the query to include the data associated with these keys;

NSMutableArray * usersRetrieved = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {    
        // objects will contain all of your objects
        for (PFObject * object in objects) {
            [usersRetrieved addObject:object[@"User"]]; // all the data should be available for the @"User" object
        }

        // objects will contain all the @"friendDetails" objects
        // usersRetrieved will contain all the @"User" objects
    }
    else {
    }
}];
```

I realize this changes your data structure a little bit, but it should give you all of the data you need.